# Add video on libreoffice ppt

Tags: video, libreoffice

I'm trying to add an mp4 video on ppt document on LibreOffice impress but the video appears as an image, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Hello. How do this have anything to do with the Ubuntu OS? Sounds like this is a good question for the libreoffice people. https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/frequently-asked-questions/

Answer (score 0):

To insert a video, from menu select `Insert → Audio or Video` and navigate your way to the appropriate directory.

From the file selection dialogue box, choose the video to be inserted. If the video is supported, you would see it inside the slide.

[image]